# Подсчёт контрольной суммы ICMP

Tags: python, python-3.x, сеть, icmp, rfc

Стоит задача собрать пакет для ICMP Echo Request. Разобрался со всем, кроме расчёта контрольной суммы пакета. Пытался нагуглить, как её считать, нашёл вот эти ссылки:
https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/11061/icmp-checksum
https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1071.txt
Как я понял, надо разбить пакет на 2-х байтовые слова (контрольную сумму изначально брать нулями), затем сложить эти 2-х байтовые слова как обычные целые числа, от результата взять 2 младших байта и инвертировать их.

---

Как я пытаюсь это сделать:

```py
def calc_checksum(packet: bytes) -> int:
    words = [int.from_bytes(packet[_:_+2], "big") for _ in range(0, len(packet), 2)]
    return 0xffff - (sum(words) & 0xffff)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    Для самопроверки отловил ICMP пакет в Wireshark,
    Заменил в нём байты контрольной суммы на нули
    """
    packet = \
    b"\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0d\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68" \
    b"\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x61" \
    b"\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69"
    expected = int.from_bytes(b"\x4d\x4e", "big") # Ожидаемая контрольная сумма
    checksum = calc_checksum(packet)
    if (checksum == expected):
        print("ok")
    else:
        print("got", checksum, "but excepted", expected)
```

В результате получаю 19796 вместо 19790. Что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неверно понял алгоритм. 2-х байтовые слова складываются как обычные числа, но старшая часть после младших двух байт суммы **не отбрасывается**, а заново прибавляется к сумме.

```py
def calc_checksum(packet: bytes) -> int:
    words = [int.from_bytes(packet[_:_+2], "big") for _ in range(0, len(packet), 2)]
    checksum = sum(words)
    while checksum > 0xffff:
        checksum = (checksum & 0xffff) + (checksum >> 16)
    return 0xffff - checksum
```